# Adding index on large table takes forever

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table (in MySQL) called `unused` with about 5.4 million rows. The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `unused` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `heading_label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_account_id` (`account_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `unused_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=80524905 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I thought queries on this table might go faster if I were to add an index. I tried running this:

```
create index heading_label
on unused (heading_label) using btree
```

I let this command run for maybe an hour or two before restarting MySQL. Even though this table has over 5 million rows, it doesn't seem like it should take over an hour to run this sort of thing. But maybe that's normal. I don't really know what I'm doing. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: It would help if you gave the real table definition.

Comment: I edited the question to include this.

Comment: First, determine if you are being I/O, CPU or memory bound by looking at your server activitity, for example, if you have a consistently low CPU usage over time you might be getting I/O bound and in that case move your `datadir` **only temporarily** to a RAM based disk (see https://learningwell.se/mounting-mysql-in-ram as reference) to speed up the index creation process. It will require to put your full database service offline for a while tough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's normal depending on your server specs.  The way MySQL creates indexes is by the table and then sorting and adding the indexes.  This means that it needs to re-write all the data, and then sort all of the data (not cheap by any means).  It depends on your server's I/O performance and how much ram you can give it.

Here are a few resources for more information...

- [A MySQL bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9544)
- [Another MySQL bug report - with a good suggestion](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24495)
- [A forum thread with some useful info](http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/slow-to-add-an-index-186951.html)

Comment: Agreed. I added an index to a 1.2 mil row table and it took half an hour.

Comment: But it depends on hardware.  On a production box (2xquad core xeon, 32gb ram, FC SAN) adding an index on an int column for a 500 million row table (30gb table size) takes about 20 minutes.  There's so much that goes in (the data type, size, I/O speed, memory size, etc) that it's impossible to say what's fast or slow without knowing all of the details...

Comment: I have a 2.4GHz processor and 4GB of RAM, if that helps.

Comment: So if my back-of-envelope calculations are correct, your table's data size is around 1gb?  If so, try bumping up the [innodb buffer pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) to around 1gb or 2gb...  See if that helps at all...