# Creating index takes too long time

Tags: mysql, innodb

About 2 months ago, I imported EnWikipedia data(http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20120211/) into mysql.

After finished importing EnWikipedia data, I have been creating index in the tables of the EnWikipedia database in mysql for about 2 month.

Now, I have reached the point of creating index in "pagelinks".

However, it seems to take an infinite time to pass that point.

Therefore, I checked the time remaining to pass to ensure that my intuition was correct or not.

As a result, the expected time remaining was 60 days(assuming that I create index in "pagelinks" again from the beginning.)

```
My EnWikipedia database has 7 tables: 
"categorylinks"(records: 60 mil, size: 23.5 GiB), 
"langlinks"(records: 15 mil, size: 1.5 GiB), 
"page"(records: 26 mil, size 4.9 GiB), 
"pagelinks"(records: 630 mil, size: 56.4 GiB), 
"redirect"(records: 6 mil, size: 327.8 MiB), 
"revision"(records: 26 mil, size: 4.6 GiB) and "text"(records: 26 mil, size: 60.8 GiB).
```

My server is...
Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-39),Memory 16GB, 2.39Ghz Intel 4 core

Is that common phenomenon for creating index to take so long days ?
Does anyone have a good solution to create index more quickly ?

Thanks in advance !

---

P.S: I made following operations for checking the time remaining.

References(Sorry,following page is written in Japanese): http://d.hatena.ne.jp/sh2/20110615

**1st. I got records in "pagelink".**

```
 mysql> select count(*) from pagelinks;
 +-----------+ 
 | count(*)  |
 +-----------+ 
 | 632047759 |
 +-----------+ 
 1 row in set (1 hour 25 min 26.18 sec)
```

**2nd. I got the amount of records increased per minute.**

getHandler_write.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash

 while true
 do
   cat <<_EOF_
 SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Handler_write';
 _EOF_
   sleep 60
 done | mysql -u root -p -N
```

command

```
$ sh getHandler_write.sh
 Enter password:
 Handler_write   1289808074
 Handler_write   1289814597
 Handler_write   1289822748
 Handler_write   1289829789
 Handler_write   1289836322
 Handler_write   1289844916
 Handler_write   1289852226
```

**3rd. I computed the speed of recording.**

According to the result of 2. ,the speed of recording is

```
 7233 records/minutes
```

**4th. Then the time remaining is**

```
 (632047759/7233)/60/24 = 60 days
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167522/innodb-takes-over-an-hour-to-import-600mb-file-myisam-in-a-few-minutes

Comment: Now THAT's what I call patience. Respect.

Comment: If you can temporarily get a server with lots of RAM (e.g. a cloud server) you might want to execute the index creation procedure in RAM as I mention in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596031/adding-index-on-large-table-takes-forever#comment122443933_4596031. With this I was able to reduce index creation time significantly with a 5GB table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are pretty big tables, so I'd expect the indexing to be pretty slow. 630 million records is a LOT of data to index. One thing to look at is partitioning, with data sets that large, without correctly partitioned tables, performance will be sloooow. Here's some useful links:
[using partioning on slow indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695768/table-with-80-million-records-and-adding-an-index-takes-more-than-18-hours-or-f) you could also try looking at the buffer size settings for building the indexes (the default is 8MB, do for your large table that's going to slow you down a fair bit. [buffer size documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_sort_buffer_size)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll review my settings.